# Exact Match without special characters in Solr

Tags: solr

My current field type in schema is currently defined to do exact match only;

```
<fieldType name="text_exact" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
         <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
         <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
         <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
         <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
         <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
         <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
   </fieldType>
```

Now, I want to implement an exact match but special characters are removed during indexing.

I read that using StandardTokenizerFactory would remove the special characters. However, I don't want the side effect of it splitting the phrase on white spaces.

Is it possible to do StandardTokenizerFactory during indexing and then using in query KeywordTokenizerFactory?

Any other ideas?

Comment: KeywordTokenizerFactory should not remove any special characters, can you give example of some of the values you are using to index/search for ?

Comment: I'm trying to negate all special characters except for & and @ which I'm replacing.

Answer (score 1):

You could use CharFilterFactories from Solr, there possible suitable factories for you:

**solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory**: it will remove all html special characters, like <, >, &, etc.

**solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory**: it will replace all characters, you could use it like regexp:

```
<charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="([^a-z])" replacement=""/>
```

it will remove all non alphabetic chars, similar to this you could remove all your special characters.

For more info - https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#CharFilterFactories

Comment: Thanks. Looks like PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory solved it. I was tinkering yesterday and the following configuration did it.              <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="(&amp;)" replacement="AND"/>
         <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="(@)" replacement="AT"/>
         <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>

Comment: Using PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory, I can now replace & with ANd and @ with AT. I'm currently trying to find the right regex configuration to remove the other special characters using PatternReplaceFilterFactory. I'm trying to instruct the filter to remove any character except a-z, &, @.